# Show microphone permission after clicking on popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension and I would like to show the microphone (possibly only once) permission prompt when the user clicks on the chrome icon. The website the extensions works on handles data over HTTPS.

How do I show a mic prompt without having to open the options.html page (and show the prompt there)?

Comment: You can make a dedicated page that looks less intimidating than the options page, then open it either in a new tab using chrome.tabs.create or in a new small window using chrome.windows.create where you can specify the type (e.g. 'popup') and size of the window.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, feel free to answer my question with your comment and I'll be happy to accept it.